# Metal Match Box Strickers Pad

Tags: home

Recently I found this Victorian metal match box and I would love to make it work again. As you can see in this pic, I've been cleaning the match friction on bottom with a metal sponge but it is still not working.
Does anyone know what I should do?
Cheers,

[image]

Comment: Are you using safety matches (which require a chemical striker) or friction matches?

Comment: Hey @WeatherVane, thanks for commenting. I'm using friction matches. Actually, there were some of the original matches inside, but of course, I've replace them with new ones.

Comment: What is the material behind the grille? Is it intended to be a replaceable striking base, with the grille holding it in place?

Comment: even though I can remove that part, it doesn't look like it means to replaced. Or, I will never find another one.

Comment: The material behind the grille may be a substance called [amadou](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amadou), which is a kind of tinder. There is a line of research for you... I am not sure that a match is supposed to be struck on the grille, but somewhere else like a wall or your fingernail. Just a guess.

Comment: Where did you get friction matches? Modern wood matches do *not* ignite, except when rubbed on the special surface on the side of the box, containing ground glass and red phosphorus. See https://www.99boulders.com/safety-matches-vs-strike-anywhere-matches